# generic SortByValue based on Numeric

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generic-programming, implicits

How do I create one implicit class for both use cases?

```
  implicit class SortableByIntValue(rdd:RDD[(String,Int)]){
    def sortByValue = rdd.sortBy(_._2)
  }
  implicit class SortableByDoubleValue(rdd:RDD[(String,Double)]){
    def sortByValue = rdd.sortBy(_._2)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

implicit class SortableByValue[N : Numeric : ClassTag](rdd:RDD[(String,N)]){
  def sortByValue = rdd.sortBy(_._2)
}
```

This should be extensible to any type for which an `Ordering` is available (`[O : Ordering]` instead of `[N : Numeric]`), if desired.